# Name of uploaded files in unicode

Tags: unicode, nancy

I´m having problems getting correct names of files uploaded to a *NancyFx web*.

I´m Spanish and we have no common characters like
`ñ á é í ó ú...` in *uppercase* and many more.

When I pick the file already uploaded from `this.Request.Files.FirstOrDefault().Name` then the names are always bad encoded.

I tried a lot of transformations with no success.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: It is an open source project, just fix the bug.  Submit your patch back to the project so everybody benefits from it.  Use their forum or chat if you need help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML page contain a

`<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

within the `<HEAD>` element?

Answer (score 0):

I have same experience with Korean file name.

And after some more googling, I found this nancyfx github issue: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1850

It's fixed bug. (but I am using nancy 0.x version, so it did not helped me.)